# Load a .tab file with different delimiters in header and body

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm having trouble reading a .tab file into Python 3.7  and am hoping someone might be able to help.  The problem is that column names in the header and the actual data use different delimiters:

```
Example of part of column row:
|      ID |             DESIGNATION |        GLON |        GLAT |          

Example of part of data:
         1      HIGALBM0.0002+0.2799      0.000153      0.279931
```

So as you can see, the header includes spaces and vertical bars, while the data has just spaces (of variable number, ranging between 4 and 10 spaces). I've tried the following in pandas:

```
pd.read_csv('filename.tab',sep='\s+',skiprows=[0,2,3],engine='python')
```

I'm skipping the first, third, and fourth lines because they're irrelevant parts of the header (date created, variable type, and units).  This doesn't work because it returns twice as many columns as there should be (~150 around ~75):

Example of column names returned:

```
'|', 'ID', '|.1', 'DESIGNATION', '|.2', 'GLON', '|.3', 'GLAT', '|.4'
```

So it seems like it is registering the bars as separate columns. This messes up the data because the first 75 returned have the values for the actual columns, but some are named with bars.  Then, the last 75 returned are just nans but with some of them having the names that are actually part of the data.

I searched both this website and the rest of the internet fairly extensively and couldn't find anything about how to do this. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you so much.

Comment: Preprocess the file to not have pipe characters in the first line before feeding it to Pandas? You could do this in-memory with an `io.StringIO()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can read headers and data with two calls to read_csv. First we read the data skipping the header row and then we read just the header and assign these column labels to the dataframe we read in the first step:

```
s="""|      ID |             DESIGNATION |        GLON |        GLAT |          
         1      HIGALBM0.0002+0.2799      0.000153      0.279931   """
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep='\s+', skiprows=1, header=None, engine='python')
df.columns = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep='\s*\|\s*', usecols=[1,2,3,4], nrows=0, engine='python').columns
df
#   ID           DESIGNATION      GLON      GLAT
#0   1  HIGALBM0.0002+0.2799  0.000153  0.279931
```